# How to share files in decentralized way between local machines, without internet?

Tags: json, database, raspberry-pi, multicast, consul

I managed to inter-connect multiple raspberry together with multicast dns and now I'm trying to share a small json between all raspberry, in a decentralized way. 97% of the time this json will be read only, but some time one of the raspberry will edit this json file.

The goal is that if raspberry #1 is down, the other raspberry will still be able to read and occasionally write into this json.

I tried with NFS but if the main node is down, the system does not work anymore. Tried Consul and it requires a central node.

Does any one have an idea to solve this? Is there a technology that allows to do that?

Comment: I use the consul kv store for exactly this purpose.  I share json files between many machines. I read and write from the kv store.  The consul server installation is typically 3 or 5 servers. You can read/write to any of these servers.  Behind the scenes one is elected a leader, but, if it fails another leader will be promoted. What about consul needs a central node?  Perhaps you could share your setup?

Comment: Thanks for your help. About Consul if there are two rpi on the network and one goes down, Consul cannot elect the only one machine remaining ((N/2)+1 rule) and sometime our rpi network can be composed of only one rpi

Comment: https://github.com/Unitech/synapsis